# Replacing row values in R based on previous rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my data frame `df`

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1))
```

I would like to have another variable `T_D` which maintains the first value when it encounters the change in the value of `A` by either `1` or `-1`and replaces the next rows by `0`

Expected Output:

```
A  T_D
1  1
1  0
1  0
1  0
0  0 
0  0
-1 -1
-1  0
-1  0 
1  1
1  0  
1  0
1  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution, this seems to work for you:

```
df$T_D = df$A*!c(FALSE,diff(df$A,lag=1)==0),
```

Find the difference between sequential rows. If the difference is 1, take the entry from column A, otherwise set to 0.

OUTPUT

```
    A T_D
1   1   1
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   1   0
5   0   0
6   0   0
7  -1  -1
8  -1   0
9  -1   0
10  1   1
11  1   0
12  1   0
13  1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr`'s [window functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) make this easy. You can use the `lag` function to look at the previous value and see if it equals the current value. The first row of the table doesn't have a previous value so `T_D` will always be `NA`. Fortunately that row will always be equal to `a` so it's an easy problem to fix with a second mutate (or `df[1,2] <- df[1,1]`).

```
library(tidyverse) # Loads dplyr and other useful packages

df <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

df %>%
  mutate(T_D = ifelse(a == lag(a), 0, a)) %>%
  mutate(T_D = ifelse(is.na(T_D), a, T_D))
```

Comment: Good catch, @docendodiscimus! I just fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$T_D <- sign(abs(df$A)*diff(c(0, df$A)))
```

Comment: This does not return the output OP requested.

Comment: That does, and that's a nice solution!

Comment: It should be ok now, it was necessary to add additioal term df$T_D <- sign(abs(df$A)*diff(c(0, df$A)))

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach would be,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, T_D := replace(A, duplicated(A), 0), by = rleid(A)][]

#     A T_D
# 1:  1   1
# 2:  1   0
# 3:  1   0
# 4:  1   0
# 5:  0   0
# 6:  0   0
# 7: -1  -1
# 8: -1   0
# 9: -1   0
#10:  1   1
#11:  1   0
#12:  1   0
#13:  1   0
```